Harry Potter fanfic involving family magic?
Im pretty sure the fic is named after the main event in the story. Had to be ffn or less likely potions and snitches site (I can’t remember how much of a role Severus had in this story)
The event is that all of Harry’s year (5 or 6th?) participate in a magical event where they are to inherit family magic or choose their path of life basically. I remember they had groups to practice meditation (Draco was in Harry’s group and Severus was their group leader) the muggleborns are invited to the event too even though there is no magical ancestor for them to inherit from so they kinda get busy work during meditation stage. At the ceremony each person goes into an individual tent with family representatives. Since Harry is an orphan Sirius stands in for James being the closest thing to a brother for Potter side. I think Remus or snape stand in for Lily. Harry drinks something to have him hallucinating his ancestors and after speaking to his mum I think he decides to have a power that isn’t exactly what dumbledore was hoping to be “the power the dark lord knows not”
At the end there is a big showdown with Voldemort at hogwarts. Everyone using family magics. I remember Draco and Narcissa were on the good side by this point. Narcissa or Bella had plant powers I think.
